# Difference between edit file and mark for edit in Perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

In perforce p4v client, there is such thing as "edit file" and marking a file for edit (after which I believe you have to submit the file/changelist back in?)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Marking for edit means that you tell Perforce that you'll inject changes in the file (and eventually commit it). Editing a file will only open the associated editor for it ?

Comment: With editing a file, will the changes be saved back to the server when I save the change? There is no clear definition of this, hence my question.

Comment: In Perforce, you usually mark a file for edit, edit the file and submit the changelist containing that file. If you edit the file (without being "marked as edit"), you probably won't be able to save it because it would be readonly. As long as you don't explicitly submit the file, changes aren't committed to the depot.

Comment: @blade4: When editing a file in a local editor, the changes are only stored on your local drive.  When you submit the changelist that contains the edited file, the file on your disk is sent to the server (more or less), and all the changes between what was on the server and the new file are stored.

Comment: TLDR: If you edit a file, it won't affect the depot until you checkout->checkin.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you sync the code to your perforce workspace, all the file has read only status.

once you do "edit", perforce change the file status from Read to write and allows you to open and do modification as you want.

but you will not be able to submit those changes without "checkout" option.

once you checkout the file, it create one change list # associated with these changes done in file, same can be submitted.

for more info, please read this...

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/edit.html